# Split a column that has an arbitrary amount of elements into a new dataframe and assign additional values

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to build a new dataframe and split the other columns that have multiple user into a bridge entity like in SQL. I can only think of iterating through each row in the DF and then each item in each column that these mulitple fields exist.

Example data:

| movieid | directors | cast |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | person1, person2, person 3 | person4, person 6, person 7 |
| 2 | person1, person 3 | person4, person 5, person 9, person 11 |

I want the bottom table, but iterating seems slow (9k lines took a min)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv(datafile, sep=str, delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
data2 = data[['show_id','director','cast']].copy()
data2[['cast', 'director']] = data2[['cast', 'director']].fillna('none')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['show_id','role','name'])

for row in data2.itertuples():
    casts = row.cast.split(',')
    directors = row.director.split(',')
    for member in casts:
        new_row = {'id': row.show_id, 'role':'cast', 'name': member}
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    for member in directors:
        new_row = {'id': row.show_id, 'role':'director', 'name': member}
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

new PERSONS df

| movieid | role | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | director | person1 |
| 1 | director | person2 |
| 1 | cast | person4 |
| 1 | cast | person7 |

Comment: I think you don't want the third column of the new data table to be "cast", right?  "person1" and "person2" are not cast members, so having the column name be "cast" doesn't make sense.  Shouldn't "cast" rather be a "role" that appears as a value in the second column?  Shouldn't the column name be something like "name" or "person"?  So you want an entry in this new table for each person on each movie, right?  So why not iterate like you say?  What's wrong with that?  It will be a good exercise if you're a beginning programmer. Do you have a question?  It doesn't seem like you've asked one.

Comment: Apologies when I was fixing things the columns shifted on my copy and paste. Fixing.

Comment: is cast also a role?

Comment: Yes, cast is actor/actress. I want to make a persons table thhat has the role of the individual (producer, director, etc) for a movie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid looping is with [**`DataFrame.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [**`Series.str.split`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

Using the sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''
movieid;director;cast
1;person 1, person 2, person 3;person 4, person 6, person 7
2;person 1, person 3;person 4, person 5, person 9, person 11
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=';')

# movieid                      director                                     cast
#       1  person 1, person 2, person 3             person 4, person 6, person 7
#       2            person 1, person 3  person 4, person 5, person 9, person 11
```

1. `melt` into `movie` / `role` / `names_csv`:

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars='movieid', var_name='role', value_name='names_csv')

# movieid      role                                names_csv
#       1  director             person 1, person 2, person 3
#       2  director                       person 1, person 3
#       1      cast             person 4, person 6, person 7
#       2      cast  person 4, person 5, person 9, person 11
```

2. `split` the `names_csv` strings into expanded columns:

```py
df = (df.names_csv.str.split(r',\s*', expand=True)
        .join(df[['movieid', 'role']]))

#        0         1         2          3  movieid      role
# person 1  person 2  person 3       None        1  director
# person 1  person 3      None       None        2  director
# person 4  person 6  person 7       None        1      cast
# person 4  person 5  person 9  person 11        2      cast
```

3. `melt` again, this time into `movie` / `role` / `name` (with some dropping and sorting if desired):

```py
df = (df.melt(id_vars=['movieid', 'role'], value_name='name')
   .drop('variable', axis=1).dropna()
   .sort_values(['movieid', 'role'], ascending=[True, False], ignore_index=True))

# movieid      role       name
#       1  director   person 1
#       1  director   person 2
#       1  director   person 3
#       1      cast   person 4
#       1      cast   person 6
#       1      cast   person 7
#       2  director   person 1
#       2  director   person 3
#       2      cast   person 4
#       2      cast   person 5
#       2      cast   person 9
#       2      cast  person 11
```